# How to make restrictions about the derived class?

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), can you prevent the following unsafe code to compile?

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        // do something assuming "this" is of type Derived:
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
    }
};

// This is OK
class A: public Base<A>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

// Crash and burn, should be prevented by the compiler
class B: public Base<A>
{
    //...
};

void f()
{
    // undefined behavior: B object was static_cast to A
    B{}.foo();
}
```

Is there a way to add some kind of restriction to class `Base` to prevent the definition of `class B` to be valid?

Comment: it isnt that unsafe. Calling `B::foo` will result in a compiler error, no?

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to do, but this seems backwards.
I would recommend going with [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design#Simple_example) instead where functionality is explicitly embedded into the class instead of the class being used as a base for another class with some functionality being "backported" back to the base.

Comment: @Kaihaku the use case is rather clear. OPs code is just a basic CRTP example nothing more

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number use case of inheritance was never clear to me. It causes more problems than gives benefits over other ways to achieve exact same thing. When it comes to extending class behaviour, inheritance should be last resort. And as CRTP is an arcane way that revolves around inheritance, I could say the same thing about that too. I would prefer if my C++ program didn't inherit my system's kernel behaviour for one, even if it might depend on it, which is often what's actually happening when CRTP is applied on everything because long arbitrary acronyms look smart.

Comment: @Kaihaku you may have opinions about CRPT, but frankly, arguing against CRPT is offtopic for this quesiton. OP is asking how to fix the code when they are using CRPT, not using it isnt a solution.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You use angle grinder to unlock your bike lock then ask how to weld it back together and me telling you to use a key instead is not a solution? Well, maybe it isn't, the key won't weld it back together, but imagine if you didn't angle grind it in the first place, the key wouldn't need to weld it back together. Just like you wouldn't need to solve this problem introduced by pointless tight coupling, which is solved... By binding the classes together even tighter.

Comment: @Kaihaku You will have to bring your issues to the C++ ISO Committee, who standardized `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Kaihaku the problem present in OPs code is only present because they are using CRPT and the actual use case does not matter because no matter what you use CRPT for the issue OP is asking about is always the same. Sorry, I really have no clue what point you are trying to make

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That there are better approaches than CRPT, even mentioned one of them. Naturally, its a comment, because its not an answer. What I don't get is your point, as you're treating my comment as an answer.

Comment: @lvella `std::cout << most_terrible_way_to_print` and similar is a part of C++ too, are you going to tell me that everything that was standardized has been necessary and perfect? Now this is indeed off-topic and I'm not going to bother anymore, but consider thinking about that part with yourself before uttering something like this again.

Comment: @Kaihaku My point is not that it is good, is that nobody goes about bothering people who implements `operator<<` to print, because it is standard and easily recognizable practice.

Comment: I cannot make sure that unsafe code *in general* does not compile, so I don't care in any special way if unsafe code *that somehow references a class that I wrote* manages to compile. It's just a particular case of unsafe code, and not a really interesting one.

Comment: @Kaihaku CRTP is a proven and tested technique successfully used in many projects with no apparent problems. Angle grinding a bike frame, to put it bluntly, isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Base<D>` constructor (or destructor) private and friend `D`.

You'll need to add

```
A()=default;
B()=default;
```

publicly, but when you do, B can't be created. Which is good.

Comment: I did not have to add `A()=default;` for my example to compile (I had to remove the instantiation of B, obviously).

Comment: @ivella seems plausible.  I don't know the exact rules for what constructors are made and how public they are in a derived class inheriting publically from a class with a private default constructor for whom they are a friend works.  I did get some errors that cleared up or made more sense when I added those `=default`s, but that might have been unrelated typos, or just less clear errors.